# Binary search tree deletion doesnot work in c

Tags: c

```
     void binarySearch(int);
     void createB(void);
     void binaryDel(int);

        int A[]={45,16,22,51,18,72,33,64,40};
        int B[32]={0};
        int i,j,x,y;

        int main(){

        scanf("%d",&y);
        createB();
        binarySearch(y);
        binaryDel(y);
        return 0;
        }



        createB(){
        B[0]=A[0];
        for(i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            x=A[i];
            j=0;
            while(B[j]!=0)
            {
                if (x<B[j])
                {
                    j=2*j+1;
                }
                else
                {
                    j=2*j+2;
                }
            }
            B[j]=x;
        }
    }}


        void binarySearch(int y){
        i=0;

          while((B[i]!=0)&&(y!=B[i])){
            if(y<B[i]){
                i=2i+1;
            }
            else{
                i=2i+2;
            }
      }

    void binaryDel(int y){
        int k,l;
        binarySeerch(y);
        k=2*i+1;
        l=2*i+2;

    while(B[k]!=0){
            k=2*k+2;
        }
        k=(k-2)/2;

    while(B[l]!=0){
            l=2*l+1;
        }

        l=(l-1)/2;
        if((B[i]-B[k])>B[l]-B[i]){
            B[i]=B[l];
            B[l]=0;
        }
        else{
         B[i]=B[k];
         B[k]=0;

        }
```

this code works sarch add and create. BUt as an argurment, i did not pass the array like `*B`, but i made global variable. IS that problem?

Error is that, after a few deletions, it gives wrong. It doesnot delete, it moves without deleting.

FOr example first i delete 16, it is correct.Then i say 51, it cant find that number in array. But it moves 40 and the root is 0. Very confusing.

edit: real code. it is not in english. first press 1 then it will create binary, then press 4, and tell the number to delete:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void binaryOlustur();
void binaryArama(int);
void binaryEkle(int);
void binarySil(int);

int A[]={45,16,22,51,18,72,33,64,40};
int B[32]={0};
int i,j,x;

int main()
{
    int y,menu;


    menu=0;

    while(menu!=5){
        printf("\n\n\n  Binary tree olusturma icin 1'e, \n  arama icin 2'ye,\n"
                 "  ekleme icin 3'e, \n  silme icin 4'e, \n  cikmak icin 5'e basin...\n");
        scanf("%d",&menu);

        switch(menu){
    case 1:
    binaryOlustur();
        for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        printf(" %d ",B[i]);
    }
    break;

    case 2:
        printf("\n Aramak istediginiz sayiyi giriniz...\n");
        scanf("%d",&y);
        binaryArama(y);
          break;

    case 3:
        printf("\n Eklemek istediginiz sayiyi giriniz...\n");
        scanf("%d",&y);
    binaryEkle(y);
       for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        printf(" %d ",B[i]);
    }
      break;

    case 4:
        printf("\n Silmek istediginiz sayiyi giriniz...\n");
        scanf("%d",&y);
    binarySil(y);
     for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        printf(" %d ",B[i]);
    }
      break;

    case 5:
    exit(-1);
      break;
      }
    }
  return 0;
}

void binaryOlustur(void ){

   B[0]=A[0];
    for(i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        x=A[i];
        j=0;
        while(B[j]!=0)
        {
            if (x<B[j])
            {
                j=2*j+1;
            }
            else
            {
                j=2*j+2;
            }
        }
        B[j]=x;
    }
}


void binaryArama(int y){
i=0;
while((B[i]!=0)&&(y!=B[i])){
    if(y<B[i]){
        i=2*i+1;
    }
    else{
        i=2*i+2;
    }

}
if(y==B[i]){

    printf("\n Eleman %d. indiste bulundu...\n",i+1);
}
else{
    printf("\n Eleman bulunamadi...\n");
}
      }



void binaryEkle(int y){
    i=0;
while(B[i]!=0){
    if(y<B[i]){
        i=2*i+1;
    }
    else{
        i=2*i+2;
    }
}
B[i]=y;
printf("\n Eleman %d. indise eklendi...\n",i+1);
}


void binarySil(int y){
    int k,l;
    binaryArama(y);
    k=2*i+1;
    l=2*i+2;

while(B[k]!=0){
        k=2*k+2;
    }
    k=(k-2)/2;

while(B[l]!=0){
        l=2*l+1;
    }
    l=(l-1)/2;
    if((B[i]-B[k])>B[l]-B[i]){
        B[i]=B[l];
        B[l]=0;
    }
    else{
     B[i]=B[k];
     B[k]=0;

    }

printf("\n %d silinip yerine %d tasindi...\n",y,B[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you indent your code please.

Comment: Where is B[] defined ?

Comment: i forgot, i wrote now but you wrote faster than me

Comment: Please post something that actually *compiles*. `createDB` is declared as returning void and defined as returning implicit `int`, and your curly braces don't match up at all.

Comment: global defined array is problem, when i change it in function, can i use it in another function without finishing other function?